# fabric.js and CMS that uses JQuery, conflict issue with $ variable

Tags: jquery, conflict, fabricjs

I am am trying to integrate fabric.js into a product I am making for a CMS. The problem is the code I am basing it on from the fabric demo site has this line above the code that starts all the fabric functions/code:

```
var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};
```

Seeing as the CMS runs ajax code in the background for notifications, I get these errors as I have 'stolen' the $:

```
TypeError: $(document) is null

TypeError: $.ajaxUpdater is not a function
```

I have tried changing removing that line and quite obviously that didn't work :). The above are both referring to the main.js file of the CMS. I changed the $ to something else (tried $$ and z) and the errors go away but then I get lots of strange behaviour when trying to select objects on the canvas and filters don't function anymore so this does not work. I have tripled checked that I replaced every instance of $ correctly. I also tried experimenting with JQuerys noConflict method but that didn't work either.

Am I missing something obvious here? I have scoured the web for help but can't find any examples of using JQuery when it's within a CMS where it is bad form to force users to modify core files when making a product. If I wanted to use the two together from scratch I think I know how I could do it but doing this without modifying the CMS core js code is proving tricky. Anyone have any tips? Many thanks.

Comment: OK I have resolved this. I just started from scratch and built it up piece by piece instead of diving in with their full example. I have now have all filters working with no conflicts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have resolved this. I just started from scratch and built it up piece by piece instead of diving in with their full example. I have now have all filters working with no conflicts!